# Is navigation2 (ros2) configurable for non-holonomic robots?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use ros2 navigation with a non-holonomic robot (wheelchair)..Is it possible/configurable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343439/is-navigation2-(ros2)-configurable-for-non-holonomic-robots?/) by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2020-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LennartL](https://answers.ros.org/users/57733/lennartl/) on 2020-08-18**:
Isn't there a confusion between non-holonomic and holonomic? I always struggle to tell them apart, but I assumed a differential drive robot is holonomic (likely a wheelchair) and a bicycle or car are non-holonmic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: yes, the demos are the turtlebot3, which is a differential drive robot. I assume that your robot wheel-chair is also differential drive? It would be a little strange if it were ackermann, but that would be pretty cool.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-07**:
Thank you so much for the answer!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-07**:
@lorenzo: please accept @stevemacenski's answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of it if you feel he has answered your question.